# How to dynamically create HTML input containing datalist using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, sweetalert2, html-datalist

I have a HTML `datalist` that looks like this

```
<input type="text" list="cars" /> 
<datalist id="cars">
    <option>Volvo</option>
    <option>Saab</option>
    <option>Mercedes</option>
    <option>Audi</option>
</datalist>
```

Now I have a `cars list`

```
var carsList = ['Volvo', 'Saab', 'Mercedes', 'Audi']
```

Now I want to create the `input field` and `datalist` and fill it dynamically using `jquery`. So basically I want to create the above html snippet dynamically using `jquery`.

So this is what I do

```
 var carInput = document.createElement("input");
 carInput.type="text";
 carInput.list="cars";
 carInput.id = "carName"
 var carDatalist = document.createElement("datalist");
 carDatalist.id="cars";

 $.each(carsList, function(i, item) {
        $("#cars").append($("<option>").attr('value', i).text(item));
 });
```

But it only creates the `input` element and not the `datalist` element with it. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I want to create an independent html since I only want to use it on `sweetalert2` popup and take input from the user.

This is what I show to the user. The popup only shows the `input` fieled but not the `dropdown`.

```
swal({
      title: 'Select a car name or define one',
      html: carInput,
      showCancelButton: true,
      width: '500px', 
      });
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to select the cars element from the page, but you haven't appended it to the page yet.  Replace `$('#cars')` with the variable for the datalist you just created.

Comment: @Taplar I do not have much idea about datalist. I am assuming `$("#cars")` is the id for the datalist? So I target that. and fill it up.

Comment: You're missing the point.  `$(<selector>)` is going to look for matching elements **in the DOM**.  As you have not appended the datalist you just made to the DOM yet, it will not find it.  Further more, since you already have the variable with a reference to it, trying to find it is pointless.

Comment: `carDatalist.innerHTML += '...yourhtml...'` or `$(carDatalist).append(...`

Comment: @Taplar I understand I am looking for something in the DOM and it doesn't exists. But in this case, I want to only look in the html I created dynamically. I have updated the question. Please check.

Comment: Right, which both statements I provided in my last comment would do. `carDatalist` **is** the html you just created dynamically

Comment: First, append to `$(carDataList)` as detailed in comments above.  2nd, you only see the input as `html: carInput` only passes the input - if you change that to `html: catDataList` you'll only see the data list.  You could try: `html: carInput + carDataList` or you could wrap both in an outer div and pass that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a template hidden div in order to be in DOM and then clone it with datalist appended:

```js
var carsList = ['Volvo', 'Saab', 'Mercedes', 'Audi'];

$(".tmp").find("#cars").html("");
$.each(carsList, function(i, item) {
    $(".tmp").find("#cars").append($("<option>").attr('value', i).text(item));
});

var div = $(".tmp").clone().show();

Swal.fire({
  title: 'Select a car name or define one',
  html: div,
  showCancelButton: true,
  width: '500px', 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9.5.4/dist/sweetalert2.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9.5.4/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
<div class="tmp" style="display: none;">
    <input type="text" list="cars" /> 
    <datalist id="cars">
    </datalist>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! This works. So the trick to define a basic structure in the DOM and manipulate that using jquery. But can you explain why did we do `$(".tmp").clone().show();` ?

Comment: Since the tmp div is hidden, I don't need to be visible. I prefer to clone it and then remove display: none and add the cloned to Swal's html.

Comment: brilliant! Never thought about that. Thanks again!